# Receive data from Push notifications on tvOS

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, tvos, apple-tv

I tried to get some data from a push notification on tvOS.

Sent a message via Firebase and received it using this function:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let content = notification.request.content
    
        // API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos)
        // let userInfo = content.userInfo
        // let title = content.title
        // let subtitle = content.subtitle
    
        completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
    }
}
```

Using [userInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent/1649869-userinfo), [title](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent/1649855-title), or [subtitle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent/1649859-subtitle) as on iOS is not possible.

If we look at the [UNNotificationContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent) interface, we see that there are many restrictions on access to content parameters (API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos)).
[image]

I printed the [UNNotificationContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent) object in the Xcode console.
And I found that the title and message text are on this object.
[image]

Is it possible to pass some useful information to Push message and parse it?

Comment: try to put object in userInfo dictionary

Comment: @Chandaboy The problem is that I don't have access to the userInfo object. Due to Apple restrictions.